# Why does Phone Update download stop after it reaches 65-70%?

Tags: lumia, update, insider-preview, nokia-lumia-630

I've registered for Windows Insider to get the latest Windows 10 Preview. I currently have Lumia 630 phone with Windows 8.1. Whenever I check the status of phone update download, it reaches up to 70% every time, but then it stops and shows the following error:

"Make sure you're connected to the Internet and try again. It's best to connect to Wi-Fi so you can avoid possible cellular data charges."

Error code: 801881d0

Although my Wi-Fi is working all time, it still shows this error. I've tried at least 7 times. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Error code: 801881d0 [usually means](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-GB/how-to/wp8/basics/solutions-to-update-issues?signin=true):

> There was a temporary issue with a server or your Internet connection during the update.

This might be at due to a fault at any point between your phone and the remote servers. It has been indicated in the past that there are fewer servers to handle the insider preview (compared to generally available/supported updates).

I'd suggest retrying later, or waiting until the update is made generally available for your phone.

Comment: Can it be due to lack of phone memory? I have 1.75 GB phone memory available of total 8 GB.

Comment: Per the link provided, you'd normally see 801881cd for not enough free space

Comment: How do I solve this problem :'(